# What (exactly) does the type keyword do in go?

Tags: go, struct, types, keyword

I've been reading [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/list) to learn [Go-Lang](https://golang.org) and so far it's going good.

I'm currently on the [Struct Fields](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/3) Lesson and here is the sample code from the right hand side:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
  X int
  Y int
}

func main() {
  v := Vertex{1, 2}
  v.X = 4
  fmt.Println(v.X)
}
```

Take a look at line 3:

```
type Vertex struct {
```

What I don't understand is, what does the `type` keyword do and why is it there?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `type` keyword is there to create a new type. This is called [type definition](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions). The new type (in your case, Vertex) will have the same structure as the underlying type (the struct with X and Y). That line is basically saying "create a type called Vertex based on a struct of X int and Y int".

Don't confuse type definition with type aliasing. When you declare a new type, you are not just giving it a new name - it will be considered a distinct type. Take a look at [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Additionally, if you have a type `A` with a method `B`. If you define another type `C` as `type C A` you won't be able to call method `B` on type `C`. That is `var c C; c.B()` won't compile. See https://play.golang.org/p/bocCzDqu3lh

Comment: Is there a way to define structs without creating a new `type`? Otherwise the syntax looks a bit redundant to me.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I had the exact same question. Is it possible to define a `struct` without a creating it as a named type?

Answer (score 22):

It's used to define a new type.

General format:
  `type <new_type> <existing_type or type_definition>`

**Common use cases:**

- Create a new type for an existing type.
  Format:
  `type <new_type> <existing_type>`
  e.g
  `type Seq []int`
- Create a type while defining struct.
  Format:
  `type <new_type> struct { /*...*/}`
  e.g
  https://gobyexample.com/structs
- Define function type, *(aka. by assigning name to a function signature)*.
  Format:
  `type <FuncName> func(<param_type_list>) <return_type>`
  e.g
  `type AdderFunc func(int, int) int`

**In your case:**

It define a type named `Vertex` for a new struct, so that later you can refer to the struct via `Vertex`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually type keyword is same with class topology in PHP.

With type keyword as though you create class in GO

Example **type in struct**

```
type Animal struct {
  name string //this is like property
}

func (An Animal) PrintAnimal() {
  fmt.Println(An.name) //print properties
}

func main() {
  animal_cow := Animal{ name: "Cow"} // like initiate object

  animal_cow.PrintAnimal() //access method
}
```

OK let's move with **type string** (is same for **int** or **float**)

```
   type Animal string
        
   // create method for class (type) animal
   func (An Animal) PrintAnimal() {
      fmt.Println(An) //print properties
   }
    
   func main(){
      animal_cow := Animal("Cow") // like initiate object
    
      animal_cow.PrintAnimal() //access method
      //Cow
   }
```

Difference between **struct** and **string, int, float** just in **struct** you can add more properties with any different data type

Opposite in **string, int, float** you can only have 1 properties, which created when you initiate your type (ex: animal_cow := Animal("Cow")

But, all type which build using type keyword can definitely have more than 1 method

Correct me if I am wrong